# How do I use auto-move?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

The Unofficial Patch for *Vampire: The Masquerade – Bloodlines* apparently added an auto-move option (listed in the [patch 9.3 changelog](https://forums.planetvampire.com/bloodlines-tech-support/unofficial-patch-9-3-released!)). How do I use that feature? Someone in a [forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/2600/discussions/0/540733524109905174/) mentioned enabling it in a CFG file, but I don't know what to add.